# Do a vertical Flip animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am currently trying to get a vertical flip animation for my card in my project's subview. I am using some dependencies (Shuffle Cocoapod), and I tried everything to attempt to get a flip animation from right to left of my card. It seems like I can change the background and other simple stuff of each single card, but nothing happens when trying to animate it. The goal would be to "show the back of the card" with another word in it (basically each card has a "front word" and a "back word". What am I getting wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Shuffle


class CardsViewController: UIViewController, SwipeCardStackDataSource, SwipeCardStackDelegate {
    
    let cardStack = SwipeCardStack()
    var actualIndex : Int = 0

    var showingBack = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(cardStack)
        cardStack.frame.size.height = 512
        cardStack.frame.size.width = 384
        cardStack.center.y =  CGFloat(cardStack.frame.size.height/2)
        cardStack.center.x =  CGFloat(cardStack.frame.size.width/2)
        cardStack.center = view.center
        cardStack.dataSource = self
    }
    
    
    func card(fromImage word: String) -> SwipeCard {
        let card = SwipeCard()
        card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right]
        for direction in card.swipeDirections {
          card.setOverlay(CardOverlay(direction: direction), forDirection: direction)
        }
        card.content = CardContentView(withWord: word)
            return card
    }
    
    
    func cardStack(_ cardStack: SwipeCardStack, cardForIndexAt index: Int) -> SwipeCard {
        let  theCard = card(fromImage: cardWords[actualIndex].word)
        actualIndex = actualIndex + 1
        return theCard
    }

    func numberOfCards(in cardStack: SwipeCardStack) -> Int {
        return cardWords.count
    }

    
     let cardWords = [
           DataOfWord(word: "comme", translation: "as"),
           DataOfWord(word: "je", translation: "I"),
           DataOfWord(word: "son", translation: "his"),
           DataOfWord(word: "que", translation: "that")]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flip type of animation with the UIView's `transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)` method

Here's some code from one of my own apps where I flip the gameboard to display the level completion score on the "other side":

```
UIView.transition(with: gameBoardCollectionView, duration: 0.75, options: [.transitionFlipFromRight]) {
     self.loadLevelEndArcadeView()
  } completion: { (complete) in
     self.animateLevelEndArcadeLabelViews()
  }
```

So, inside the transition code block, you just load the views you want and when the animation completes, you'll be displaying something that represents the back side of a view.  There are also other transition animations you can call upon if you want.